# Implement gallery in libgdx for android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need your help i want to implement menu like gallery in android.
I want implement like this http://prntscr.com/4k6vze
But i have no expiriance with libgdx. Give me suggest pleas or give me good tutorial. Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put images like sprites or actors and using gesture detection move that images https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection